# Activation with System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#

Activation with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` causes the following error. A summary of the errors and details of these errors are listed later in the log...

> Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\MCIS\Desktop\Sanjivini\2.7\SanjiviniCommonApp.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>   + Failed to load the runtime. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700)

Answer (score 1):

[ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) needs the correct version of the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) runtime in order to run the application. Check these items:

- That the .NET runtime is installed on the client computer [(newest .NET runtime)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)
- That you have the correct version of .NET runtime (4.0, 3.5 SP1, etc.)
- If the computer / Windows version is 32-bit (*x86*), check that the application isn't compiled to run only on 64-bit (*x64*).